# Sul passato prossimo, che non c'è, di ‘dirimere’

Tags: verbs, past-tense

Come - fra l'altro - vedete nella pagina internet qui sotto, il passato prossimo del verbo dirimere non esiste, ciò che ho dovuto accertare - perché suonava male - proprio oggi quando stavo per scrivere 'Peppa, giusto ieri, *ha dirimesso* ogni incertezza al riguardo'.

Ciò premesso, chiedo:

1) Perché il passato prossimo di 'dirimere' non esiste?

2) Cosa è opportuno fare in questo caso per esprimere che l'azione del 'dirimere' è avvenuta nel passato?

[image]

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Il verbo *dirimere* [viene dal latino *ĕmĕre* con il prefisso *dis*](http://www.treccani.it/vocabolario/tag/dirimere/). Secondo il [dizionario Lewis-Short](http://www.perseus.tufts.edu/hopper/text?doc=Perseus%3Atext%3A1999.04.0059%3Aentry%3Demo) la coniugazione è *ĕmo, ēmi, emptum, ĕmĕre*, il cui significato è “prendere” (lo stesso di *accipere*).

Una parola come *promptus* ha, in italiano, l'esito *pronto*. Quindi forse “dirento” *potrebbe* essere un participio passato accettabile, ammesso che sia usato; i dizionari lo negano, sembra. Viceversa, [*redimere*](http://www.treccani.it/vocabolario/tag/redimere/), che è composto di *red* e *ĕmĕre*, il participio passato ce l'ha, *redento*.

Bizzarrie dell'uso della lingua.

Escluderei recisamente *dirimesso* come participio passato; se proprio ti serve al passato, adopera un sinonimo come *sciogliere*, *decidere*, *troncare*:

> Peppa, giusto ieri, ha sciolto ogni incertezza al riguardo

Comment: Ovviamente, sono d’accordo. Frugando nel pagliaio del difettoso riconoscimento ottico del testo, su _Google Libri_ sono riuscito a trovare qualche ago: «La questione è ancora lungi dall’essere **direnta**»; «[Non] sembra che la giurisprudenza abbia all’attualità **dirento** i persistenti dubbi…»; «Parimenti nessuno ignora come tutte le questioni gravissime sorte fra i Missionari di quelle regioni siano state **dirente** dall’autorità dei Romani Pontefici». Mi sembra un latinismo pedantesco, da usarsi, se si vuole usare, solo in testi iperspecialistici in cui si richiede la massima formalità.

Answer (score 1):

Anche in Italiano, come in altre lingue, esistono i verbi irregolari o 'difettivi' e derimere è uno di questi:

Premessa:

> - Con questa scheda speriamo di risolvere i dubbi di molti lettori su forme verbali irregolari o avvertite come "strane" e inconsuete. Si tratta di una lista (ordinata alfabeticamente) di verbi irregolari o difettivi di cui vengono messi in evidenza congiuntivi, participi passati e altre forme che possono far nascere qualche incertezza.

***[Dirimere](http://www.accademiadellacrusca.it/it/lingua-italiana/consulenza-linguistica/domande-risposte/verbi-difficili)***, passato remoto e participio passato

> - La coniugazione del passato remoto del verbo dirimere prevede, per alcune persone, doppie forme, ambedue corrette: io dirimei/dirimetti, tu dirimesti, egli dirimé/dirimette, noi dirimemmo, voi dirimeste, essi dirimerono/dirimettero; ***il participio passato non è in uso.***

(www.accademiadellacrusca.it)

Aggiungerei che non è un verbo molto comune e un sinonimo può essere usato a seconda dei casi:

***[Dirimere](http://dizionari.corriere.it/dizionario_sinonimi_contrari/D/dirimere.shtml)*** v.tr.(sinonimi)

> - 1. (una controversia) mettere fine, concludere, terminare, porre fine, definire.
> - 2. (un litigio, una discussione) risolvere, appianare, aggiustare, comporre, giudicare.

P.S. [Wiktionary](https://it.wiktionary.org/wiki/dirimere) cita la seguente frase:(penso che *dirento* non  sia corretto o veramenre raro)

> - I collegianti rimandarono la discussione a quando la Corte ***avesse dirento*** il conflitto.

Comment: In effetti non darei molta retta a quella voce del Wiktionary, dato che si contraddice molteplicemente: in tutti i dizionari che cita come fonti si dice correttamente che “dirimere” manca del participio passato; poi c'è quell'esempio con *dirento; e nella tabella della coniugazione c'è un *dirimuto di fantasia. La vita è troppo corta e ho smesso di sprecarla per correggere cose su it.wikipedia e siti parenti, ma magari qualcuno ha tempo di farlo. (Quanto all'esempio, viene da [qui](http://tinyurl.com/nryuzka), una relazione alla Camera che non prenderei esattamente a modello di italiano.)

Comment: @DaG - l'ho citato perchè mi sembrava divertente. In realtà poi La Crusca dice che il p.p. non è usato, lasciando intendere che probabilmente  esiste in qualche forma arcaica.

Answer (score 1):

Riguardo il come esprimere quello che penso sia il senso della frase originale in linguaggio comune:

`Peppa, giusto ieri, ha chiarito ogni dubbio al riguardo`

Per quanto riguarda il verbo in sé, `dirimere` difetta (in quanto appunto verbo difettivo) di alcune forme (che semplicemente non esistono) e non è usato comunemente, si preferisce il sinonimo `risolvere`.